# OSGI OBR repository hosting?

Tags: java, osgi, obr

Does anyone know of any services that provide OBR for hosting my own Bundles?

Something like github - but for bundles.

(If not - did anyone ever create their own OBR server, and how hard was it?)

EDIT: I found one solution by [Nexus Pro](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/07/nexus-pro-support-for-osgi-bundle-repositories/), but it seems like its too expensive for mere mortals (as price for pro is nowhere to be seen).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SpringSource](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/), [Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org/obr/repository.xml), and the [OSGi Alliance](http://www.osgi.org/Repository/HomePage) have repositories and ServiceMix has its own bundles but all are privately maintained with varying levels of public influence.

There's an [old public repository out there](http://oscar-osgi.sourceforge.net/) that Richard Hall used to maintain. This is back before Oscar became Felix, so you'd have to contact Richard, who is very active on Felix, about this OBR's usefulness.

Setting up your own OBR isn't terribly difficult. Apache Felix offers an [OBR bundle](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-osgi-bundle-repository.html) to get things started. An OBR is really just an XML index with files linked within akin to a Maven repository, so you could set up your own OBR on any host as long as you structure things right.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any info on how the web front-end is supposed to look like? For example, do we just do GETs on the repository URL, and then GETs on each particular bundle url to download it? I hope i am not confusing you...

Comment: Yes, first you GET the XML index (eg. http://felix.apache.org/obr/releases.xml). From the index, you can see what is available. The first item in the Felix OBR is has this attribute: uri="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.bundlerepository/1.4.1/org.apache.felix.bundlerepository-1.4.1.jar"
From that you can download the jar or have your OBR client download and install.

Answer (score 4):

The open source edition of Nexus now provides (experimental at the moment, but it seems to work fine) support for generating [OBR repositories](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-obr-plugin).

You can create a 'virtual repository' with format: 'OBR', and point this to another repository. This virtual repository will monitor the contents of the repository and generate OBR metadata.

[Karaf Cave](http://karaf.apache.org/index/subprojects/cave.html) is also an OBR repository, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to Nexus for Maven hosting is [Apache Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/). Once tools like [Felix bnd](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) plugin build a repository.xml for your project you can put it in the standard maven repository to host the OBR metadata. The other maven repository hosting solution is [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Although this might be a little bit late, but I am currently working on an open source (EPL) software repository server, called [Package Drone](http://packagedrone.org), with the primary focus on OSGi bundles.

It does support Eclipse P2, Maven and Maven Tycho, Bndtools or manual upload. You can also access the repository as a P2 or OSGi R5 XML Index repository.